# EmberJS; Can't create record with relationships

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've a got User, Chat and Message model to create chat functionality in our app.

User:

```
messages:      DS.hasMany 'message'
chat:          DS.hasMany 'chat'
```

Chat:

```
users:         DS.hasMany 'user'
messages:      DS.hasMany 'message'
```

Message:

```
user:          DS.belongsTo 'user'
chat:          DS.belongsTo 'chat'
message:       DS.attr 'string'
```

In this situation I already have a `chat` and a `user` object and what I'm trying to do is create a `message` in this chat which belongs to the user sending it.

I'm using the following to do so:

```
controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend Ember.Evented,
  needs:      'application'
  app:        Ember.computed.alias 'controllers.application'
  actions:
    sendMessage: ->
      content = Ember.$('.new-message input').val()

      message = @store.createRecord 'message', message: content
      message.set 'user', @get 'app.model.user'      
      message.set 'chat', @get 'model'

      message.save().then =>
        console.log "done"
```

But it results in the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Cannot call get with 'isEmpty' on an undefined object
```

Two things that make the problem disappear:

- Removing the `message.set 'chat', @get 'model'` line
- Creating a message in the database (it works if it's not the first message being created)

Comment: how come, when youre setting the user, youre 'app.model.user' and when youre setting to chat, you just call 'model'?  Also is there a specific chat record youre setting it to?

Comment: Where is this code, in a controller? you should be modifying the model through the controller.

Comment: The code is in a controller action. `app` on this controller computes to my application controller, which has an `RSVP.hash` with `user` on it. But as stated in the question, it probably has something to do with the `Chat` model.

Comment: Try to assign user and chat when creating record as second parameter. Maybe it will help.

Comment: Turns out it was a bug.. Upgrading to beta.14 fixed it..

Comment: @TimBaas can you please specify which version you were on while suffering from the bug and which version exactly solved the issue? beta.14 does not seem very specific version. Looks like I'm suffering from the same.